# Vlookup variable reference issue

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I'm having an issue with a variable worksheet within a vlookup formula.  I believe it is something to do with how I'm referenceing the worksheet.  I have looked a numerious other blogs on this and used different techniques but I'm still getting a "Run-time Error 1004".  Below is a summary of the related code - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PopulateDynamicReport()

    Dim getcolumnPDR As Range
    Dim getConfigPosition As Range
    Dim getFieldDescriptionPDR As String
    Dim getFormulaPDR As Variant
    Dim columnletter As String
    Dim myrange As String
    Dim getColumnLetter As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim lLastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    lLastrow = FindLastRow("Pricing Analysis")

    Sheets("Pricing Analysis").Cells.Clear

    counter = 1

    Set getConfigPosition = Sheets("Config").Cells.Find(What:="Field Description", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(counter, 0)

            columnletter = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, -1)
            Set ws = Sheets(getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2).Value)

            Sheets("Pricing Analysis").Cells(1, columnletter).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],ws.range(!C[-4]:C[-2]),3,FALSE)"

            counter = counter + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-4]," & ws.Name & "!RC[-4]:RC[-2],3,FALSE)"
```

You can not mix the vba objects into formulas that you write on a sheet, but you can use the vba objects to help build the string you need to write the formula, as I have done above.

Comment: Thank you for your input however I'm still getting a "Run-time error 1004"

Comment: Scott - Typo inputting your code - it does work and thanks again for the support.  It's greatly appreciated.